# How to reduce output for a custom API Endpoint in java/groovy

Tags: java, groovy, confluence-rest-api

I am working on improving a custom search for our Confluence-Server platform.
We have a plugin called Scriptrunner that allow us to use Groovy instead of Java for the code.

The code I am working on is a Search API endpoint, and it currently works fine but returns a lot of unnecessary information and even duplicate, so I want to narrow down the search output in the most efficient way.

The platform have a javadoc that I am trying to use for the implementation, link : https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/7.8.1/com/atlassian/confluence/search/v2/SearchManager.html

I want to implement the following part

```
search(ISearch search, Set<String> requestedFields)
Perform a search with a given criteria, the returns searchResults only have the fields requested in the projection filled out, no other fields are valid in the searchResult.
```

But I cannot understand how to properly generate the `Set<String> requestedFields` .

Here is my attempt to do so :

```
import...

def searchManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SearchManager)
def paramQueryString = "ArticleThatWillBeDeleted"
def query = BooleanQuery.andQuery(new TextQuery(paramQueryString));
def sort = new RelevanceSort();
def searchFilter = SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter.getInstance();
def searchContent = new ContentSearch(query, sort, searchFilter, 0, 100);

Set<String> requestedFields = new HashSet<String>();
requestedFields.add("displayTitle");

def searchresult = searchManager.search(searchContent,requestedFields)

return searchresult.getAll()
```

If I want to use the other method

```
search(ISearch search)
Perform a search with a given criteria.
```

The script works perfectly fine, but returns a lot of information that I want to cut down.

Beside the method I want to implement, I am also open for any other type of suggestion where I can specify only the information I want to be outputted so I can safe output size and processing power.

P.S.
I have already try to ask the same question in great detail on their community page, but figured I could use some developer help with that as I just learned about Java/Groovy from working on that.

In great detail : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Need-to-optimize-the-output-of-a-custom-Search-API-Endpoint-in/qaq-p/1515177

**UPDATE:**

Here is the working code implemented as an API endpoint:

```
import com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.AuthenticatedUserThreadLocal
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator


import com.atlassian.confluence.search.service.ContentTypeEnum
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.SearchManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.searchfilter.SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.ContentSearch

import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.*
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.sort.RelevanceSort
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.SearchSort

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

import java.util.HashSet

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

testSearch(
    httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["access_group_1","access_group_2"]
) { MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->

    def searchManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SearchManager)

    // Query can be of any type noted here:
    //https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/searching-using-the-v2-search-api/
    def paramQueryString = (queryParams.get(new String("q"))).get(0)
    def query = BooleanQuery.andQuery(new TextQuery(paramQueryString));
    def sort = new RelevanceSort();
    def searchFilter = SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter.getInstance();
    def searchContent = new ContentSearch(query, sort, searchFilter, 0, 100);

    def searchresult = searchManager.search(searchContent)

    return Response.ok(new JsonBuilder([results: searchresult.getAll()]).toString()).build()
}
```

When I call the API

```
http://10.10.10.11:8080/rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/testSearch?q=ArticleThatWillBeDeleted
```

I am getting the following JSON response

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "displayTitle": "ArticleThatWillBeDeleted",
            "handle": {
                "className": "com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page",
                "id": 359071873
            },
            "lastUpdateDescription": "",
            "ownerTitle": null,
            "spaceName": "Employee Team Space",
            "creatorUser": {
                "backingUser": {
                    "active": true,
                    "lowerName": "vnikolov",
                    "directoryId": 142049281,
                    "fullName": "Vasil Nikolov",
                    "emailAddress": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                    "email": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                    "name": "vnikolov",
                    "displayName": "Vasil Nikolov"
                },
                "lowerName": "vnikolov",
                "key": {
                    "stringValue": "8a606c8c56a371040156a37301341285"
                },
                "fullName": "Vasil Nikolov",
                "email": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                "name": "vnikolov"
            },
            "resultExcerpt": "this is the body of the article that will be delted.",
            "ownerType": null,
            "lastModifier": "vnikolov",
            "urlPath": "/display/WIT/ArticleThatWillBeDeleted",
            "resultExcerptWithHighlights": "this is the body of the article that will be delted.",
            "explain": {
                "present": false,
                "empty": true
            },
            "lastModifierUser": {
                "backingUser": {
                    "active": true,
                    "lowerName": "vnikolov",
                    "directoryId": 142049281,
                    "fullName": "Vasil Nikolov",
                    "emailAddress": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                    "email": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                    "name": "vnikolov",
                    "displayName": "Vasil Nikolov"
                },
                "lowerName": "vnikolov",
                "key": {
                    "stringValue": "8a606c8c56a371040156a37301341285"
                },
                "fullName": "Vasil Nikolov",
                "email": "vnikolov@domain.com",
                "name": "vnikolov"
            },
            "extraFields": {
                "content-version": "1"
            },
            "lastModificationDate": "2020-10-20T20:42:27+0000",
            "type": "page",
            "content": "   \nthis is the body of the article that will be delted.\n ",
            "creationDate": "2020-10-20T20:41:46+0000",
            "personalLabels": [],
            "status": "current",
            "spaceKey": "WIT",
            "contentVersion": 1,
            "creator": "vnikolov",
            "displayTitleWithHighlights": "ArticleThatWillBeDeleted",
            "homePage": false,
            "sanitisedContent": "this is the body of the article that will be delted."
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting 4 times the body (resultExcerpt , resultExcerptWithHighlights , content , sanitisedContent)
All I need from that is just the `content` and if possible to chop it down a limited size or character length.

When I try to implement the `requestedFields` by adding the following line and modify the `searchresult`

```
    def requestedFields = [ 'content', 'displaytitle' ] as Set
    def searchresult = searchManager.search(searchContent,requestedFields)
```

The JSON response I am getting is that :

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "resultExcerpt": "",
            "explain": {
                "present": false,
                "empty": true
            },
            "resultExcerptWithHighlights": "",
            "extraFields": {},
            "displayTitleWithHighlights": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The other thing I noticed is that in the working example the returned class is :
`com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.lucene.LuceneSearchResult@1233a8a4`
and in the `requestedFields` attempt the result class is :
`com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.ProjectedSearchResult@6c688cdd`

I want to find a way to control the output of the API, it does not necessary need to be the `requestedFields` method I am trying to implement.

Comment: so, are you asking about how to create `Set<String>` in groovy???

Comment: You can say that, yes. Because the way I implement that in my code snippet does not seems to work the way I expect it to.

Comment: `[ 'aaa', 'bbb' ] as Set` is a set of strings.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to get the to the same place as what I have used :( the property of the result is `all:[com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.ProjectedSearchResult@6c688cdd]` instead of `com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.lucene.LuceneSearchResult@1233a8a4` and I dont know how to even approach this.

Comment: why you have decided that you have more data then requested?

Comment: For example, the content body of an article is stored 4 times in to 4 different properties within 1 result while I need it only 1 time and preferably cut down to a limited amount of characters or so.
I dont know how to see the properties of an object in the javadoc but in the following class almost all the methods correspond to a property but without the get/in in front. : https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/5.9.1/com/atlassian/confluence/search/v2/AbstractSearchResult.html

Comment: show the exact example how it's stored 4 times. it seems we are discussing code that you did not shared.. if you are passing the properties as input - you got the property list.

Comment: @daggett I have provide an update in the question, hope that makes it more sufficient.

Comment: How you get the json?

Comment: by using the JSON builder `return Response.ok(new JsonBuilder([results: searchresult.getAll()]).toString()).build()` , this seems to unwrap any object and extract the property-value from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223762/discussion-between-vasil-svilenov-nikolov-and-daggett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `JsonBuilder` renders all object properties and not only the fields you requested from server.

the simplest way i see to render requested fields:

```
def requestedFields = [ 'content', 'displaytitle' ] as Set
def searchresult = searchManager.search(searchContent,requestedFields)

def table = searchresult.getAll().collect{row-> 
    requestedFields.collectEntries{fldName->  
        [ fldName , row.getField(fldName) ] 
    }
}
    
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(table).toPrettyString()

Response.ok(json).build()
```

Comment: I am getting `null` values,  but if I run  `searchresult.getProperties()` there is a nested object that need to be expand to get to the properties, so if I run the `searchresult.getAll()` in your `def Json` it succesfully expand all the properties. I also dont know groovy, most of the time I write scripts in PowerShell with the help of .NET and the syntax here is very unfamiliar to me so I failed to adjust your script to mine.

Comment: After further digging, turned out `row` inherit all the methods, so getField does work but I get a return only some, for the `handle` and `urlPath` , and everything else is `Null`

Comment: I think I made it to work but I might need a better syntax, instead of calling a functions I am referecing the variable with a dot notation `[ fldName , row."${fldName}" ] ` but I think my syntax here is not right  because it works in the console but not when I try it as an API endpoint.

Comment: had a case-sensitive typo, now it works! I hoped for the method but this is also good enough. I also dont know the best approach but went with that `[ fldName , row."$fldName" ]`